# Google+ sign in, PHP one-time-code/server-side flow without "Silex/twig"

Tags: php, google-plus

example code from [Google+ Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)

```
  // Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
  // Store it in the session for later validation.
  $state = md5(rand());
  $app['session']->set('state', $state);
  // Set the client ID, token state, and application name in the HTML while
  // serving it.
  return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
      'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
      'STATE' => $state,
      'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
  ));
```

[image]

Question: How to server-side work without silex/twig ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this [Client Library(PHP)](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/list)
please test this codes it works fine
index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$data['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$_SESSION['state'] = $data['state'];
?>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<head>
  <!-- BEGIN Pre-requisites -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      var po = document.createElement('script');
      po.type = 'text/javascript';
      po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
  </script>
  <!-- END Pre-requisites -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Add where you want your sign-in button to render -->
<div id="signinButton">
  <span class="g-signin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    data-clientid="Your clientid"
    data-redirecturi="postmessage"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-callback="signInCallback">
  </span>
</div>
<button id="signoutButton" style="display:none" onclick="signout()">signout</button>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function signInCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['code']) {
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
    $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');
    $('#signoutButton').attr('style', 'display: block');
    var state = '<?php echo $_SESSION['state']; ?>';
    var param = new Array();
    var param = [authResult['code'],state];
    // Send the code to the server
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'plus.php?storeToken&state',
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(result) {
        // Handle or verify the server response if necessary.
       console.log(result);
        alert('connected');
      },
      processData: false,
      data: param
    });
  } else if (authResult['error']) {
    alert('Could not automatially log in the user');
     console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}

function signout(){ 
       gapi.auth.signOut();
        $('#signoutButton').attr('style', 'display: none');
        $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: block');
        console.log('sign out');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

plus.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT ID';
  $client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);
  $client->setClientSecret('Client Secret');
  $client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');

 $code = explode(",",file_get_contents('php://input'));

  if (isset($code[1]) && $code[1] === $_SESSION['state'])
{
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
  $client->authenticate($code[0]);
  $token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());

  // Verify the token
  $reqUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' .
          $token->access_token;

  $req = new Google_HttpRequest($reqUrl);

  $tokenInfo = json_decode(
      $client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());

  $userId = $tokenInfo->user_id;
  $userEmail = $tokenInfo->email;

  // If there was an error in the token info, abort.
  if (isset($tokenInfo->error)) {
    print $tokenInfo->error;
  } 
  // Make sure the token we got is for our app.
   if ($tokenInfo->audience != $CLIENT_ID) {
    print "Token's client ID does not match app's.";
  }

print 'Token from result: ' . print_r($token, true);
print '<<<<<<<<<<< tokenInfo >>>>>>> ' . print_r($tokenInfo, true);

}
else
{
          echo "Invalid state parameter";
}
```

don't forget to add your `CLIENT ID` and `Client Secret`.
Sign out not working in localhost.

Comment: for store token in session use `$_SESSION['token'] = json_encode($token);` in `plus.php`

Comment: How `('php://input')` works ? there seem no such file while the sample works. thanks.

Comment: `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body.more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 3):

There are two answers, as there are two libraries you're wanting to do without.

For the first (Silex):

```
// Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
// Store it in the session for later validation.
$state = md5(rand());
$app['session']->set('state', $state);
```

This is simply storing a session variable for later use.  This can be done easily in PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

$state = md5(rand());
$_SESSION['state'] = $state;
?>
```

Later on, you would verify the correct state value from the client by comparing what the client sends to `$_SESSION['state']`.

The second part (Twig):

```
// Set the client ID, token state, and application name in the HTML while
// serving it.
return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
    'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
    'STATE' => $state,
    'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
));
```

This is simply replacing values in the rendered HTML with known values. You could do this by replacing every instance of *`{{ VARIABLE_NAME }}`* in the sample index.html with a PHP variable (such as changing `{{ CLIENT_ID }}` to `<?php echo $CLIENT_ID; ?>`) and then, of course, setting that variable in your code.

You would then call your PHP script instead, and have your script read in and return the `index.html` file.

**Edit**
For [Step 7: Confirm the anti-request forgery state token on the server](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_7_confirm_the_anti-request_forgery_state_token_on_the_server)

```
// Ensure that this is no request forgery going on, and that the user
// sending us this connect request is the user that was supposed to.
if ($request->get('state') != ($app['session']->get('state'))) {
  return new Response('Invalid state parameter', 401);
}
```

Instead use:

```
if ($_REQUEST['state'] != $_SESSION['state'])) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
  echo "Invalid state parameter";
  exit;
}
```

For [Step 8: Initialize the Google API client library and start the Google+ service](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_8_initialize_the_google_api_client_library_and_start_the_google_service):

For every line that is `return new Response('{Message}', {HTTP status code});` replace it with

```
header("HTTP/1.1 {HTTP status code});
echo "{Message}";
exit;
```

Then instead of

```
// Store the token in the session for later use.
$app['session']->set('token', json_encode($token));
$response = 'Succesfully connected with token: ' . print_r($token, true);
```

put

```
// Store the token in the session for later use.
$_SESSION['token'] = json_encode($token));
$response = 'Succesfully connected with token: ' . print_r($token, true);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate      
[Step 7: Confirm the anti-request forgery state token on the server](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_7_confirm_the_anti-request_forgery_state_token_on_the_server),  [Step 8: Initialize the Google API client library and start the Google+ service](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_8_initialize_the_google_api_client_library_and_start_the_google_service)

Comment: isn't `$request->get('state')` a Silex ?